# How to adjust img into a div in bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Actually my logo size is large. And i want to fit it in the left side div of navbar. But it is going outside the div. Don't know what the issue is?

index.js

```
<div class="navbar-brand"  >
    <img class="logo-Image" src="./assets/images/kwikModelLogo.png" alt="KiwiModel" />  
</div>
```

style.css

```
header.navbar .navbar-brand {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: .8rem 1.5rem; 
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

I want the div to be adjust within the left div of navbar.

Comment: It's not very clear, can you format your code and add the HTML code please, so we can help you

Comment: Thank you @Asmoth. I fixed it by giving width to img according to the navbar

Answer (score 0):

I think this style will help you

```
img.logo-Image {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

also you can adjust **width** and **padding** value as per your requirement to position the brand logo.